# Very slow people detection

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to detect people in real time and set cursor on them position. I made python-script using OpenCV, but it is working very slow. How can I make it faster?

```
def target():
with mss.mss() as sct:
    filename = sct.shot()
src_gray = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
peopleRectDetector = prd.PeopleRectDetector()
peopleRects = peopleRectDetector.detect(src_gray)
for (x, y, w, h) in peopleRects:
    cv2.rectangle(src_gray, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), 255, 2)
    a = int(x+w/2)
    b = int(y+ h/4)
    win32api.SetCursorPos((a,b))
    break
```

Comment: I don't know what is this mss but I think your code is slow because of the file operations. I recommend to you to check the profile of your code with for example Pycharm.

Comment: Okay, it really depends on how the detection is happening, how many people are in each frame and how powerful is your machine where your running the code.

Comment: What's the point of having a loop, that `break`s after the first iteration? And how is this function called?